# Retrieving Fraction part from a double in C++

Tags: c++, double, fractions

I am taking input in double and then typecast it in order to take out the fraction part. However when the input is a small number lets say `4294967295.2` , the fraction part is retrieved, but when I input a larger number then this, the fraction part becomes zero. I know it is some number thing but I am a little new to this stuff so. What is the reason for getting fraction part as zero when input number is like `9007199254740991.2`.? Here is the code:

```
unsigned long long first,second;
double a,b,remainderA,remainderB;
cout << "Enter first number:\n"<< endl;
cin>> a;
cout << "\nEnter second number:\n"<< endl;
cin >> b;

first=(unsigned long long) a;
second=(unsigned long long) b;

remainderA=a-first;
remainderB=b-second;


cout<<remainderA<<endl;
```

Regards

Comment: see: [what every computer scientist should know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a matter of precision. A double has 52 Bits of mantissa which gives about 15-17 bits of decimal digits. Your second example hits this Limit and the fraction (0.2) most likly gets not stored within the double.

Answer (score 0):

When the input number is large enough to reside in the targeted type it will cast to 0. you are taking the input in double which has a larger range. and casting it into unsigned long long which has a smaller range. That's why the problem is happening.

You may have a look at the following

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Comment: ok so what do I need to do to retreive the fraction part even when the number is big?

Comment: for a big big enough number you need to manipulate that from string. Make a google search on bigNumber you will get enough resource.

Answer (score 0):

double has range :1.7E +/- 308 (15 digits)

and unsigned long long has range :0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615(20 digits)


and you are casting first=(unsigned long long) a; 
eg. if you are inserting 9007199254740991.2 in "a" then 
the value inserted is

```
    a = 9,0072e+015 
    first :90071992547409910
```

Therefore **its a matter of precision**. That's why you are getting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers store a certain number of digits. If the number is too long, then the fractional part is already past the limiting precision of the data type.

To get more significant figures than `double`, try `long double`. For example, this outputs  `0.2` (approximately, again due to limited precision): https://ideone.com/i8Yyt0

You might want to use `std::floor` to perform rounding, since casting a large number to an integer type causes undefined behavior it's outside the integer type's range. (It can crash, like dividing an integer by zero.)